# Altering the keypress event of certain keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, keypress, keyboard-events

I am working on a project which shows the character code of each key that is pressed down inside a text box.

My problem is that when certain keys, namely: Shift, Backspace, Space are pressed down, their character codes appear like: 16, 8, 32.

I want these keys to retain their normal behavior when pressed. So that space causes a space in the text box, and backspace deletes the character, and so on...but the rest of the keys to continue outputting their character code.

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check for the keys and handle accordingly. Here's a demo:

```js
document.getElementById("test-textbox").addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
  
    if(code === 16 || code === 8 || code === 32) //check if space, shift, or backspace
        return; //if yes, allow
    
    console.log(code); //if not, log value  
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent entry
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test-textbox">
```

This will allow the shift, backspace, and space keys to be pressed, but all others will be logged.

Comment: @mattHunting10 No problem, glad to help. If it did help you consider upvoting and possibly accepting :)

Comment: The only other question I have. Is how can I make SHIFT key output the capital of a letter. For example if someones presses "shit + h" to output 73 instead of 72.

Comment: You might want to use a regex to allow capital letters @mattHunting10, I'm a bit short on time right now, sorry!

Comment: @mattHunting10 Had a bit of time, [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/6jfraynu/1/) a demo.

Comment: When you hold Shift + h for example, it outputs H in the text box. what I am looking for, is for it to output the keyCode of "H" as opposed to "h" in the console. 

Thanks anyways though, you've already been a huge help.

Comment: @mattHunting10, I see. As far as I know, that is most likely impossible.

Comment: I have been researching everywhere and can't seem to find the solution either. I am going to wait and ask again here, so hopefully somebody knows!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you.

```
var elementID = document.getElementById('elementID');

elementID.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key == 32 || key == 8 )
        event.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: I am trying to Ouput the character code of all keys except a few of them. So I already have to include preventDefault() to avoid outputting the character Code AND the letter like 65a as opposed to 65. So that's why your example won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you…

1. don’t call the `preventDefault` method on the event object, and
2. don’t return `false` from the event handler

…you should be fine.

In particular, the handler…

```
function showCharCode(event) {
  // NOTE: Don’t call `event.preventDefault()` here.
  document.querySelector('.char-code').textContent = event.charCode;
  // NOTE: Don't return false here.
}
```

… will still propagate the event to the default textbox (or input, or contenteditable) element.

Comment: But if I dont call the preventDefault method. Then I will get both they keycode of the key as well as the character associated with it. Like 65a. instead of 65.

Comment: @mattHunting10 So you want the keycode of the characters to appear in the textbox *instead of* the actual input, *except* for the space, backspace and the shift keys?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the response. But the person above already got the solution.